# Set decimal values to 2 points in list under list pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to set max decimal values upto 2 digit for result of a nested list. I have already tried to set precision and tried other things but can not find a way.

```
r_ij_matrix = variables[1]
print(type(r_ij_matrix))
print(type(r_ij_matrix[0]))
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option("display.precision", 2)
data = pd.DataFrame(r_ij_matrix, columns= Attributes,  index= Names)
df = data.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'center')])])
df.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
df.set_caption('Table: Combined Decision Matrix')
```

[image]

Comment: can you please share first few rows , so that we can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: `df.to_dict()` or `df.loc[:10].to_dict()` would help

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with the `apply()` method of the dataframe. You can do something like that :

```py
df.apply(lambda x: [[round(elt, 2) for elt in list_] for list_ in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

`applymap` seems to be good here:
but there is a BUT: be aware that it is propably not the best idea to store lists as values of a df, you just give up the functionality of pandas. and also after formatting them like this, there are stored as strings. This (if really wanted) should only be for presentation.

```
df.applymap(lambda lst: list(map("{:.2f}".format, lst)))
```

Output:

```
                    A                   B
0  [2.05, 2.28, 2.49]  [3.11, 3.27, 3.42]
1  [2.05, 2.28, 2.49]  [3.11, 3.27, 3.42]
2  [2.05, 2.28, 2.49]  [3.11, 3.27, 3.42]
```

Used Input:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [[2.04939015319192, 2.280350850198276, 2.4899799195977463],
  [2.04939015319192, 2.280350850198276, 2.4899799195977463],
  [2.04939015319192, 2.280350850198276, 2.4899799195977463]],
    'B': [[3.1144823004794873, 3.271085446759225, 3.420526275297414],
  [3.1144823004794873, 3.271085446759225, 3.420526275297414],
  [3.1144823004794873, 3.271085446759225, 3.420526275297414]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by copying the list to another with the desired decimal points. Thanks everyone.

```
rij_matrix = variables[1]
rij_nparray = np.empty([8, 6, 3])
for i in range(8):
  for j in range(6):
    for k in range(3):
        rij_nparray[i][j][k] = round(rij_matrix[i][j][k], 2)
 rij_list = rij_nparray.tolist()
 pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
 data = pd.DataFrame(rij_list, columns= Attributes,  index= Names)
df = data.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'center')])])
df.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
df.set_caption('Table: Normalized Fuzzy Decision Matrix (r_ij)')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).